# Error after importing class using alt+enter

Tags: java, android-studio

[image]

I am trying to learn java from a book I ordered.I followed the instructions exactly but the code still shows error and will not let me compile and run. The book told view would be displayed in red which signified error. It told to alt+enter and import class "View". No further instructions to help the error remaining

Any help will s=be appreciated

Comment: Please try to create `topClick()` and `bottomClick()` methods outside the `onCreate()` method.That is the cause of the error!!!

Comment: You cannot declare/define a method within another method. You can see what are methods and how to define a method here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm

Answer (score 0):

Method `topClick()` is declared inside of the `onCreate()` method. You should end `onCreate()` method scope with `}` and then declare `topClick()` method. Simplified example:

```
public class MyActivity MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }

    public void topClick(View v) {
    ...
    }
}
```

instead of the incorrent one:

```
public class MyActivity MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        public void topClick(View v) {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

(Look at closing brackets in your files, it seems that you should add a closing curly bracket (`}`) after last line of the `onCreate()` method - right before `public void topClick(View v)`).